# Firebase Cloud messaging silent push notification to iOS not working while the prompting ones do

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

using Firebase Cloud messaging to send notification to iOS, the prompting ones work, however, the silent one never trigger any codes.
[image]

tested both on real device and simulator, iOS version is the latest, my codes with the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate get triggered as expected when prompting push is received.
however, I put codes in application.didReceiveRemoteNotification and the codes never get triggered..., the func ffl is a thin wrapper of OSLog. the UserOb singleton is a simple object to write to UserDefaults.Standard so I can check the result offline. see below....

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    ffl("didReceiveRemoteNotification")

    UserdOb.shared.apDelegateReceived()
    AVUtility.shared.avAvPlayCaf(audioCaf: .alertSimple)
    ffl(userInfo.description)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

below is code for delegate registration, again, prompting ones works. silent ones remain ... too silent (nothing happened)

```
fileprivate func registrateMe(application:UIApplication){
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions:UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {granted, error in
            if granted{
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            }
        })
    }else{
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

I have tried a lot of payloads of FCM (by postMan). here are some of them:nether works..., see below

```
{
"to": "[token]",
 "data":{
     "key1":"value1"
     "key2":"value2"
 },
 "collapse_key":"update request",
 "content_available":true,
 "priority":"normal",
}

{"to" : "[token]",
 "content_available": true,
 "priority": "high",
 "data" : {
   "key1" : "abc",
   "key2" : 123
 }

 "content_available": true,
   "apns-priority": 5,
   "data": {
     "some-key": "some-value"
   }

 {
    "to": "[token]",
    "content_available":true,
    "content-available":"1",
    "aaa":"aaaa"
 }
```

** the Apple APN service certificate is input into the Firebase App configuration. see screenshots [image]

and I have the FCM server key in the authorization and it works find by header: Authorization:key=[], I don't think the prompting ones will work if these are not configured correctly.
the app has been tested both in active and background mode, either way the prompt ones work and the silent ones don't.

Comment: You need an APNs certificate for that.

Comment: what is the state of the app, is it in the background or forground?

Comment: I assume by APN certificate you mean the APNs Auth key? (see revision above). let me know if not. and prompting works either active or background. silent ones not working either way.